# How to use token refresh in ranm8/requestify?

Tags: laravel, node-webkit, nw.js, dingo-api, requestify

I have my api with dingo/laravel. Normally works without problems for mobile (android).

My AuthController@token in dingo/laravel:

```
public function tokenRefresh()
    {
        $token = JWTAuth::getToken(); // Header:Auth..Baerer ...
        if (!$token) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('Token not provided');
        }
        try {
            $token = JWTAuth::refresh($token);
        } catch (TokenInvalidException $e) {
            throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('The token is invalid');
        }

        return $this->response->withArray(['token' => $token]);
    }
```

i making another app with nw.js, and i use it requestify module. 
My example login request:

```
 requestify.request(this.authUrl, {
        method  : 'POST',
        body    : {
            email: document.getElementById('email').value,
            password: document.getElementById('password').value
        },
        headers : {
            'X-Forwarded-By': 'me'
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(function (response) {
            var body = response.getBody();
            alert(body.token);
        });
```

its request normally return valid token. its ok.

How about expires token? 
What should I do?
Maybe, kind of like ajaxSetup for all request before.
I need to automatic refresh token when token expires. 
What do you recommend?